# Como ordenar pela relevância do Like?

Tags: mysql, operador-like

Estou fazendo um autocomplete que faz uma requisição à uma url, que por sua vez consulta no banco de dados.

Essa consulta é feita com o `LIKE`. Eu utilizo `%$termo%` para poder fazer a consulta, porém eu gostaria de ordenar o resultado de acordo com a relevância do `LIKE`, e não por ordem alfabética.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Exemplo: Ao consultar `car`, a ordem ser algo parecido com isso:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo LIKE '%car%' ORDER BY aqui_vem_a_magica();
```

- **carr**o
- **car**o
- refor**car**
- colo**car**

Ou seja a ordem não pela ordem alfabética, mas pela proximidade de caracteres que estão no início da palavra...

Comment: Porque o `carro` tem que vim primeiro do que `caro`?

Comment: Porque eu quero... Kkkkk... Brincadeira... Porque a ideia é pegar primeiro o like que tá mais para o início da palavra e o restante depois

Comment: Cometi um grave erro de digitação, desculpa

Comment: Posso postar  uma solução em MSSQL e você adapata ao Mysql? :)

Comment: @Marconi seria legal se eu conseguisse adaptar a pergunta a um contexto global de SQL

Comment: O Jeferson postou em Mysql e eu em Sql-Server, o contexto ficou um quase totalmente "global". =D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `LOCATE` do `MySQL` dentro do `ORDER BY`:

```
SET @termo := 'car';

SELECT *
  FROM tabela
 WHERE campo LIKE CONCAT('%', @termo, '%')
 ORDER BY LOCATE(@termo, campo);
```

Explicando a `query` acima:

- A variável `@termo` é criada e recebe o texto que será buscado na tabela;
- O `CONCAT` irá colocar `%` no início e final do texto, resultando em `%car%` no caso do exemplo, que indica que `car` pode estar em qualquer posição do `campo`;
- A cláusula `ORDER BY` irá levar em consideração a posição onde o texto procurado se encontra na coluna `campo`, retornando primeiro as que tem o texto `car` no início do texto;

O resultado não será igual ao que foi apresentado no exemplo porque o método apresentado acima não leva em consideração apenas o começo e o final da coluna `campo`. Leva em consideração a posição na frase inteira apresentando-o da seguinte forma:

```
╔═══╦════════════╗
║   ║ campo      ║
╠═══╬════════════╣
║ 1 ║ caro       ║
║ 2 ║ carro      ║
║ 3 ║ colocar    ║
║ 4 ║ reforcar   ║
╚═══╩════════════╝
```

> **[`LOCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)**
>
> ... returns the position of the first occurrence of substring **substr** in string **str**.

Em tradução livre:

> ... retorna a posição da primeira ocorrência de uma substring **substr** em uma string **str**.

---

> **[`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)**
>
> For quoted strings, concatenation can be performed by placing the strings next to each other.

Em tradução livre:

> Para strings destacadas, concatenção pode ser realizada colocando as strings uma após a outra.

Comment: Apesar das outras serem mais votadas, eu optei por marcar essa como útil por ter mais explicações. Usuários novato se beneficiarão mais de explicações tais como estas do que simplesmente uma solução pronta (entenda que isso não é uma crítica às outras respostas, apenas um diferencial).

Answer (score 6):

Você pode fazer isso verificando em que posição essa string se encontra no seu campo, com a função `INSTR`, por exemplo:

```
SELECT INSTR('meucarrovermelho','car');
```

Nesse caso vai retornar o número 3, já que "car" se encontra na 3 posição da palavra "meucarrovermelho".

Com isso você pode fazer sua ordenação inicialmente por ele e depois por ordem alfabética.

Sua query ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabela 
WHERE campo LIKE '%car%' 
ORDER BY INSTR(campo ,'car'), campo;
```

Comment: Tem como colocar na resposta o que a função `INSTR` faz?

Comment: claro, vou complementar

Comment: Ah, legal, o `INSTR` retorna a posição que a string se encontra :p

Answer (score 4):

Que tal usando `Case When` no `Order By`?

```
 select * from MinhaTabela
 WHERE texto LIKE '%car%'
 order by
 case when texto like 'car%' then 0 else 1 end
```

Ordene de forma ascendente o texto onde iniciar com `car`.

***Observação:*** Essa solução funciona no *Sql-Server*, pois não tenho servidor `Mysql` instalado.  O [Case](https://imasters.com.br/artigo/18681/mysql/utilizando-select-case-com-mysql/?trace=1519021197&source=single) do `Mysql` funciona um pouco diferente, então é preciso ajustar.