# Como ordenar consulta no MYSQL por relevância? (primeiro resultados que o termo está no titulo, depois no conteúdo)

Tags: mysql, select, order-by

Tenho uma tabela da seguinte forma:

```
id|nota|titulo       |ingredientes
1 | 3  |pão de batata|batata;farinha;agua;ovo
2 | 2  |bacalhoada   |bacalhau;batata;pimentão
3 | 1  |batata frita |batata
```

Quando eu fizer uma busca que contenha o termo 'batata" quero que ele traga esses três resultados, porém primeiro traga todos os que tem batata no título, depois por ordem decrescente da nota, os critérios ficariam assim:

1. Contém batata no título
2. Contém batata no ingrediente
3. Ordenar por ordem decrescente de nota

Nesse exemplo, o resultado seria

1. Pão de batata
2. Batata frita
3. Bacalhoada

Comment: isso que vc quer é definir um ranking por relevância, e pode conseguir isso se usar um índice *fulltext* para as duas colunas

Comment: Você pode ordenar baseado no resultado do 'like'. Talvez seja isso que você esteja procurando:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205331/como-ordenar-pela-relev%C3%A2ncia-do-like e também:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144394/order-sql-by-strongest-like

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ordenar pela relevância do Like?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205331/como-ordenar-pela-relev%c3%a2ncia-do-like)

Answer (score 3):

Caso básico de uso do `ORDER BY`

```
... sua query ...

ORDER BY titulo       LIKE "%batata%" DESC, 
         ingredientes LIKE "%batata%" DESC, 
         nota DESC
```

Isto funciona pelo simples fato de o `LIKE` retornar *bool* (zero ou um), e o `DESC` fazer com que os resultados `1` (encontrado) venham em primeiro

Se os critérios são simples, dispensa mexer nas estruturas. Se não é bem do jeito que foi perguntado, pesquise por [Full Text Search](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=full+text+search) aqui mesmo no site (mas para o seu exemplo é algo como matar pomba com ICBM).