# Como fazer busca por relevância no MySQL (priorizar palavra inteira)

Tags: php, mysql, select

Tenho um site de receitas em PHP e MySQL.

A consulta é:

```
SELECT receita FROM receitas WHERE receita LIKE '%mac%'
```

Quando busco por "mac", ele traz "macarrão" e "big mac". Queria que no resultado primeiro trouxesse "big Mac" e depois "macarrão" pois o "big mac" tem o termo "Mac" inteiro enquanto "macarrão" é somente parte do texto.

É possível fazer isso? Buscar primeiro palavra INTEIRA e depois apenas o trecho.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ordenar pela relevância do Like?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205331/como-ordenar-pela-relev%c3%a2ncia-do-like)

Comment: Pesquise por full-text search. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss na realidade não tem ligação. Neste caso citado a relevância é por proximidade do início

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, como o Sorack disse, essa não funciona muito, por exemplo, torta de maça veio antes, qualquer termo que comece com mac pode aparecer antes

Comment: Ok, removi meu voto, mas deixarei o comentário por ser intrinsecamente relacionada. Talvez a que citei seja útil para alguém que venha até esta pergunta.

Comment: @anonimo o único problema de o usar o `MATCH` é que ele retornará apenas os registros que tiverem `mac` inteiros, ou seja, ele ignora `macarrão` por exemplo. E usando o `'mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE`, neste caso, ele atua igual um `LIKE ` normal não colocando as palavras cheias em primeiro. Mas é BEM interessante essa alternativa, estou fazendo uns testes para ver como se comporta.

Answer (score 2):

Eu consegui usando regexp do mysql.

Criei a seguinte expressão regular:

```
(^|\s)mac($|\s)
```

A expressão avalia o texto seguindo as regras:

- `(^|\s)` - Antes da palavra tem que haver um ou mais espaços ou é o inicio dela
- `mac`    - Depois do espaço tem que haver a palavra `mac`
- `($|\s)` - Depois da palavra tem que ter um ou mais espaços ou é o final dela

Se por acaso o título da busca passar por essa avaliação, então esse registro tem que estar logo no inicio.

Para fins de teste eu criei o seguinte código:

```
    /*
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS receitas (
        id         INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        titulo     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        receita    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )  ENGINE=INNODB  CHARACTER SET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO receitas VALUES 
    (null, 'Big Mac', '2 hamburguers, alface, queijo...'),
    (null, 'Miojo', 'ferva a água...'),
    (null, 'Macarrão', 'ferva a água...'),
    (null, 'Torta de Maçã', 'Vá até um Mac Donalds e pague no caixa uma torta...'),
    (null, 'Maç', 'Vá até um Mac Donalds e pague no caixa uma torta...');
    */

    SELECT titulo 
    FROM receitas
    WHERE titulo LIKE '%mac%'
    ORDER BY
        CASE 
            WHEN titulo REGEXP '(^|\s)mac($|\s)' THEN 1 
            # aqui é onde acontece a mágica
            ELSE 2
        END
    ;
```

Na ordenação é feita a avaliação. Se ele entrar na avaliação o valor atribuído será `1` enquanto os demais que não entrarem terão um valor de `2`.

*O problema...*

O resultado obtido é:

```
Big Mac       // correto
Macarrão      // correto
Torta de Maçã // correto
Maç           // < --- este deveria estar no inicio
```

Sendo que o título `Maç` deveria (teoricamente) estar entre os primeiros... Isso acontece porque o `regexp` busca exatamente a palavra digitada.

Para resolver isso você pode criar um campo de `slug` na tabela aonde você mantém os espaços e altera os caracteres especiais toda vez que você salvar um novo registro, para que a busca seja feita por lá.

**Outra opção**

Uma outra solução, indicada nos comentários pelo @anonimo, é usar funções de procura por textos completos com a função `MATCH` ao invés do `LIKE` no MySQL.

Para isso é preciso alterar o campo da tabela que será feito a busca com:

```
ALTER TABLE receitas ADD FULLTEXT(titulo);
```

Com isso, você poderá realizar a união de duas consultas diferentes:

```
    SELECT id, titulo 
    FROM receitas
    WHERE MATCH(titulo) AGAINST('mac')
        UNION
    SELECT id, titulo 
    FROM receitas
    WHERE MATCH(titulo) AGAINST('*mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

A primeira é a consulta com a palavra inteira, ele pegará apenas os registros com o texto cheio. A segunda pegará tudo que contém 'mac'(funciona igual ao `LIKE` neste caso). O `UNION` combinará os resultados sem deixar registros duplicados.

Comment: Eu gostei da primeira solução, ela atribui um peso para cada tipo de consulta e ordena por esses pesos. Ficou bem sofisticado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques sim... Mas tem aquele efeito colateral que para mim não é um problema. Mas...